# Why is this returning -nan?

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    float averageyear;
    float averagemonth;
    float sumyear;
    float rainny;
    int year = 2020;
    int rain[5][12];
    const char* month[12] = {"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"};
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {   printf("*****Year %d*****\n",year+i);
        for (j=0;j<12;j++)
        {
        printf("%s: ",month[j]);
        scanf("%f",&rainny);
        sumyear+=rainny;
        averageyear=(float)sumyear/12;
        }
        printf("Total of %d is %.2f\n",year+i,sumyear);
        //averageyear=(float)sumyear/12;
        printf("Average of %d is %.2f\n",year+i, averageyear);
        sumyear=0;

    }
}
```

The code gives me the output

```
Total of 2020 is -nan
Average of 2020 is -nan
```

But when I switch `averageyear=(float)sumyear/12;` to outside the for loop (The commented line), it gives me the right output. I don't see any difference between those 2 positions of the code. Please help me clarify this. Thank you!

Comment: `sumyear` is not initialized.

Comment: Usually when a `float` or `double` number is `NaN` it's because it was not initialized.

Comment: In C uninitialized local variables really *are* uninitialized. They will have an *indeterminate* value (look at it as garbage). If you're unlucky it can be a so-called *trap representation* which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

Without initializing variables declared in block-scope (like `sumyear`) they contain whatever the memory had present prior to the program running.

If this value was not a number, which is a special number in floating point representations to handle things that aren't rational numbers, then adding anything to it will also yield NAN (not a number).

Initialize the `sumyear` (and your other variables) to valid values, and your program will work correctly regardless of whatever memory it is assigned to use.

Comment: Thank you. Just fixed it into sumyear = 0 and it works perfectly now!